# How to draw a 'felt pen' style circle in XAML without ends joining up

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm designing a Metro Style App with XAML, and I have a need to draw a circle where the ends don't properly meet up, as if it had been scribbled with a red felt pen.  Something like this:

[image]

How could this be done in XAML?

Comment: Is it allowed to be perfectly round/elliptical?

Comment: I was hoping for a shape that wasn't a perfect circle with a small bit missing, if that's what you mean.  Better if the ends can be slightly 'off' meeting up.  Your answer is spot on though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, get ready for a little bit of XAML:

```
<Path Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"              
        Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="5">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure IsClosed="False" StartPoint="5,50">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>

                                <ArcSegment Point="50,5" Size="80, 40" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                <ArcSegment Point="95,50" Size="50, 50" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                <ArcSegment Point="50,95" Size="50, 50" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                <ArcSegment Point="5,55" Size="55, 100" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />

                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

This code produces:

[image]

You can tweak the coordinates a bit for a more|less rounded result and maybe use BezierSegments.

Comment: Ah, now I see how you would do it - thank you!  Hadn't thought of using four arcs, but then I'm quite inexperienced with XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You could draw a closed shape with no outline filled with red color using [available shapes in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx). In particular you could base your shape outline on the [BezierSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.beziersegment.aspx).